# Filtering in Linked Sources using the QueryString as paramters in CAML(Select Command)  and not XSLT filtering

Tags: data-view-web-part, 2007

Did anybody tried Filtering Linked Data Sources using the QueryString as paramters in CAML (Select Command) and not XSLT filters

AggregateDataSource  with Parameter

```
<DataSources><SharePointWebControls:AggregateDataSource runat="server" IsSynchronous="false" SeparateRoot="true" id="New_x0020_Data_x0020_Source1"><sources><SharePointWebControls:spdatasource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" UseInternalName="true" selectcommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ID&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Counter&quot;&gt;{ID}&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;OrderBy&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;PublishedDate&quot; Ascending=&quot;FALSE&quot;/&gt;&lt;/OrderBy&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;ViewFields&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ContentTypeId&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Title&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;_ModerationComments&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;File_x0020_Type&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Body&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;NumComments&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;PostCategory&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;PublishedDate&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;_ModerationStatus&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ID&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ContentType&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Modified&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Created&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Author&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Editor&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;_HasCopyDestinations&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;_CopySource&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;_UIVersion&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;_UIVersionString&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Attachments&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;FileRef&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;FileDirRef&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Created_x0020_Date&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;FSObjType&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;FileLeafRef&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;PermMask&quot;/&gt;&lt;/ViewFields&gt;&lt;/View&gt;"><SelectParameters><asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="5A97A2C9-5609-47DE-A259-9DF3CCD3BB7D"/></SelectParameters><DeleteParameters><asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="5A97A2C9-5609-47DE-A259-9DF3CCD3BB7D"/></DeleteParameters><UpdateParameters><asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="5A97A2C9-5609-47DE-A259-9DF3CCD3BB7D"/></UpdateParameters><InsertParameters><asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="5A97A2C9-5609-47DE-A259-9DF3CCD3BB7D"/></InsertParameters></SharePointWebControls:spdatasource><SharePointWebControls:spdatasource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" UseInternalName="true" selectcommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;_ModerationStatus&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Text&quot;&gt;Approved&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;OrderBy&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Created&quot; Ascending=&quot;FALSE&quot;/&gt;&lt;/OrderBy&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;ViewFields&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ContentTypeId&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Title&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;_ModerationComments&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;File_x0020_Type&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Body&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;PostTitle&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;PostID&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;_ModerationStatus&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ID&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ContentType&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Modified&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Created&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Author&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Editor&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;_HasCopyDestinations&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;_CopySource&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;_UIVersion&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;_UIVersionString&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Attachments&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;FileRef&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;FileDirRef&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Created_x0020_Date&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;FSObjType&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;FileLeafRef&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;PermMask&quot;/&gt;&lt;/ViewFields&gt;&lt;/View&gt;"><SelectParameters><asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="C5635ED3-F6B9-48B3-9A79-1C2B5C256701"/></SelectParameters><DeleteParameters><asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="C5635ED3-F6B9-48B3-9A79-1C2B5C256701"/></DeleteParameters><UpdateParameters><asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="C5635ED3-F6B9-48B3-9A79-1C2B5C256701"/></UpdateParameters><InsertParameters><asp:Parameter Name="ListID" DefaultValue="C5635ED3-F6B9-48B3-9A79-1C2B5C256701"/></InsertParameters></SharePointWebControls:spdatasource></sources><aggregate><concat name="data source"><datasource name="Posts" id="0" Type="SPList"/><datasource name="Comments" id="1" Type="SPList"/></concat></aggregate></SharePointWebControls:AggregateDataSource></DataSources>
```

Parameter Bindings

```
<ParameterBindings><ParameterBinding Name="dvt_apos" Location="Postback;Connection"/><ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/><ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/><ParameterBinding Name="ID" Location="QueryString(ID)" DefaultValue="1"/></ParameterBindings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the values of Query String parameters by setting up parameters in your DVWP and then using those values in your filters.  The net effect of this is to alter the CAML to contain the filtering.

Creation of each parameter will create a line in the ParameterBindings section like this:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="ID" Location="QueryString(ID)" DefaultValue=""/>
```

You can then use that value in your CAML, something like this:

```
selectcommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ID&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Counter&quot;&gt;{ID}&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/View&gt;"
```

Comment: @Marc : I did used QueryString PArameters in normal DVWP many times, but it doesn't work with LinkedDataSources, Just let me know if it should work then I will invest more time OR I am planning to use SPServices to replicate Linked Datasources :)

Comment: @Marc : Even a normal paramter like this <ParameterBinding Name="ID" Location="None" DefaultValue="1"/> is not working :(

Comment: Can you post your AggregateDataSource and ParameterBindings sections?

Comment: Novice:
This does work just as Marc posted.  He's personally shown me these and I know it works.  Keep plugging away at it.  There is a learning curve with XSL, but you eventually will get it.

Comment: @Marc :  I added the datasource and parameter bindings

Comment: @Novice I've noticed all of your CAML appears to be correct.  I even went ahead and made it readable, so I can double check it.  It appears right, but I always like to keep it simple when troubleshooting.  Have you tried this piece of CAML?:

<View>
 <Query>
   <Where>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='ID' />
         <Value Type='Counter'>{ID}</Value>
      </Eq>
   </Where>
</Query>
</View>

I'd like to see if this works, so that way we can get rid of some variables...

Answer (score 0):

@Marc: can I access to CAMLVariable like HttpvDir or HttpPath or HttpHost, if I am creating AggregrateDataSource..?

I am not able to get any of the values for above parameters though I have declare them in ParameterBindings section..

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. You need to add DataFormParameter. Please refer to http://spisnotthedevil.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/dynamic-filter-on-linked-datasource.html for more details.

Eg:

```
<ParameterBindings>
   . . .
  <ParameterBinding Name=”Department” Location=”QueryString(Dept)” DefaultValue=”Human Resources”/>
```

```
      <SelectParamters>

            . . .
```

. . .

```
</SharePoint:SPDataSource>

      <SharePoint:SPDataSource . . .   SelectCommand=” . . . ” . . .>

      <SelectParamters>

            . . .
```

. . .

```
</SharePoint:SPDataSource>
```